# Codeigniter Routes Regex one of two

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes, multiple-languages

I want

```
en/careers to career
fa/careers to career
careers to career
```

I tried `$route['(en|fa)(.+)/careers'] = 'career';`

but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Make `en/` and `fa/` optional:

```
(en/|fa/)?careers
```

Comment: but this is not working. i have also tried (en\/|fa\/)?careers but no use :(

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex  in the Routes.php

```
$route['en/careers|fa/careers|careers'] = 'career/index';
```

graphical explanation :

[image]

**UPDATE:**

But I think it would make more sense to send the language letters "en"  or "fa" as an argument to the career controller/method to make tests ...etc, so it looks like this :

```
www.example.com/en/careers = www.example.com/careers/lng/en
www.example.com/fa/careers = www.example.com/careers/lng/fa
www.example.com/careers = www.example.com/careers/lng/en 
//(assuming that en is the default language if no language was specified)
```

if that makes sens then you should go for those 3 rules like so

```
$route['(en)/careers'] = 'career/lng/$1';
$route['(fa)/careers'] = 'career/lng/$1';
$route['careers'] = 'career/lng/en';
```

and here is the lng() method that goes inside careers.php

```
 public function lng($lang_id)
 {
    if($lang_id == "en")  
        echo "welcome"; 
    elseif($lang_id == "fa")
        echo "خوش آمد";  // not sure if this is correct in "fa" language :p
 }
```

Note : you can change $1 to a numeric id if your languages have ids stored in a database ...etc

```
$route['en/careers'] = 'career/lng/1';
$route['fa/careers'] = 'career/lng/2';
$route['careers'] = 'career/lng/1';
```

then your lng() method will look like this

```
 public function lng($lang_id)
 {
    if($lang_id == 1)  
        echo "welcome"; 
    elseif($lang_id == 2)
        echo "خوش آمد";  // not sure if this is correct in "fa" language :p
 }
```

I hope that helps

Comment: thanks for detail answer but my case is it must be en/careers because its not only single file but the whole project is that way. btw above regex is not working too,

Comment: I guess its some kind of bug with ci to use pipeline | with regex

Comment: @Wasim try to add index after the controller name or the name of the method in the controller, i updated my answer

Comment: I already have done with 3 routes but need in single regex like you answered at first line regex.

Comment: @Wasim I'm sorry that's the 2 cents that I have, it should work if your .htaccess is set to remove index.php from uri, otherwise, add index.php before the controller name like so :  $route['en/careers|fa/careers|careers'] = 'index.php/career/index'; good luck